# How to solve maven provided scope issue

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm building a custom sonar plugin which is a maven project.

Sonar asks to mention it's required `sonar-plugin-api` dependency as scope `provided`. I think it's okay because it will run inside sonar container which will have this jar.

In my use case I want to add additional dependency of `httpclient`. If I add it under default scope, it refuses to build, throwing below error:

```
[ERROR] This dependency must be declared with scope <provided>: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.364 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-05T13:52:22+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.18.0.372:check (default-check) on project myPlugin: Unsupported dependencies
```

If I change the scope of `httpclient` to `provided`, it will build but will not work in sonar as it does not have this jar in its env.

All the dependencies in `httpclient`, including `commons-logging` is mentioned as scope - `compile`.

This is what my current pom looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.plugin.sonar</groupId>
    <artifactId>myPlugin</artifactId>

    <!-- this is important for sonar-packaging-maven-plugin -->
    <packaging>sonar-plugin</packaging>

    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>myPlugin</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <!-- minimal version of SonarQube to support. Note that the groupId was "org.codehaus.sonar" before version 5.2 -->
            <version>6.7</version>
            <!-- mandatory scope -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- facing problem after adding this dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.0.372</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <pluginKey>MyCustomPlugin</pluginKey>
                    <pluginClass>com.plugin.sonar.MyCustomPlugin</pluginClass>
                    <pluginDescription>Sonar plugin of Test</pluginDescription>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any suggestions, how to solve it?

*Thank You*

Comment: Maybe Sonar manages external dependencies in another way. I mean, maybe `provided` is fine and you have to place the JAR in some specific folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Sonar Maven plugin contains a [check](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-packaging-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/pluginpackaging/CheckMojo.java#L35) that disallows commons-logging and LOG4J because SonarQube supports only SLF4J.

So what you can do is switch to SLF4J and exclude `commons-logging` from the `httpclient` dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is probably a better approach than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry in the `<dependencyManagement>` section to manage `commons-logging` to `provided`, i.e.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>...</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

For the version: Use the one you find in your `dependency:list` at the moment.